# UNION ALL for 2 cursors in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, union-all

I have an existing procedure (SProc1) which returns a cursor with 10 columns, and another (Sproc2) which also returns a cursor with 10 columns with the same column as SProc1.

Can I call Sproc2 inside Sproc1 to do the UNION ALL?

How to retrieve the records from Sproc2 to do the UNION ALL with SProc1?

Comment: can you share the sample code?

Comment: Why you can't use one cursor with "union all"?

Comment: you can't call Sproc2 inside Sproc1 and do the `UNION ALL` if it returns a ref cursor. 
but you can create a [pipelined function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADDCI/pipe_paral_tbl.htm#ADDCI2140).